# Model, ModelMap, and ModelView in Spring MVC- which one to use

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

so many pages and links i found, but none of them have clear answer. Even spring docs doesn't say anything about it.

So which one to use on what context?

Answer (score 0):

**Model** is an interface that defines methods for adding/removing attributes.

From the javadoc:

> Primarily designed for adding attributes to the model. Allows for
>   accessing the overall model as a java.util.Map.

**ModelMap** is just a Map implementation used for storing values that will be used in the UI.

**ModelAndView** is an object that combines a Model object (for storing values that will be used in the UI) and a View (used for resolving UIs components like jsp or templates). It was designed to provide both model and view in a single return.